# How do I use the findCorrelation in the Caret Package in R when I have missing values?

Tags: r, correlation, missing-data, r-caret

I am trying to impute missing values but am coming up with a `system is computationally singular` error. Hence, I am trying to drop collinear variables.

I tried the following code:

```
indexesToDrop <- findCorrelation(cor(df_before, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"), cutoff = 0.85)
```

Which producers the following error:

```
Error in findCorrelation_fast(x = x, cutoff = cutoff, verbose = verbose) : 
  The correlation matrix has some missing values.
In addition: Warning message:
In cor(as.matrix(df_before), use = "pairwise.complete.obs") :
  the standard deviation is zero
```

Comment: `colindiag` from `metan` package helps you to identify collinear variables.

Comment: Does colindiag handle missing data? I am getting Error in eigen(cor.x) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Comment: ok, now I am thinking of a two step approach. 1) use a simple imputation (e.g. colmeans) to fill in the missing data , 2) use the simplified imputed data to remove the colinear columns from the original data, and 3) then run a more complicated imputation algorithm on the revised original data.